# ORA-12842: Cursor invalidated during parallel execution error during alter table move subpartition

Tags: oracle, compression, partition, subpartition

Had a task to compress some large tables to reduce storage costs by using Oracle's Advanced Compression. Here is the statement :

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ' || i_table_name || ' 
                          MOVE SUBPARTITION '|| i_sub_part_name || ' ONLINE 
                          ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED 
                          UPDATE INDEXES NOLOGGING '
```

This statement is called by 15-20 independent jobs each with their own subpartition name. For most of the time, we get no error for majority of subpartitions, but in each run there are 1-2 cases where ORA-12842 error is thrown. There is no parallal hint, or alter session command for parallel execution, no indexes are being dropped during execution nor another session changing the same subpartition.

Any other reason why this could happen?

Comment: Do their run period for those 15-20 jobs overlap for the common subpartitions ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, they all start at the same time, but for separate partitions, that is each job compresses 1 subpartition. I was thinking maybe UPDATE INDEXES command is causing the error, since not all indexes are declared with local keyword. Can this be true?

Comment: Yes, it is true. The error is thrown every time the underlying object's structure is changed. I think the table parallel degree is above 1, so parallel execution is automatically started